# Disable fields until main field is populated

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

So, im creating this form. There are 3 main fields at the top. ignore the others. Organisation Name, Department and Address. the user must input some data in the Organisation field for Department and Address to be useable.

[Here is the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGo5B.png)
here is a mockup i did. this is what it should look like if the user hasnt put any information into the organisation name.

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8oan.png)

```
      <div class="control-group required">
            <label class="control-label">Organisation Name <em>*</em></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-append input-prepend">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="Organisation-Name">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" href=""> Find</button>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Department</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-append input-prepend">

                    <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="Department">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" href=""> Find</button>

                </div>
                <span class="help-inline"><i class="help" title="Enter the Department of this Opportunity.">Help</i></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Address</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-append input-prepend">

                    <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="Address">
                    <button type="button" class="btn" href=""> Find</button>

                </div>
                <span class="help-inline"><i class="help" title="Enter the Address for this Opportunity.">Help</i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

ive managed to make it look like this using the suggestions below. the bottom 2 fields need to go back to normal when i add data in the Organisation field

[image: Result]

Comment: Please add your markup here so that we can help. Images of rendered HTML is no use for future readers or potential answerers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out: https://jsfiddle.net/x0fwf6ro/

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body> 

Name: <input id="name" type="text"> <br/>
Age: <input id="age" type="text" disabled> <br/>
Roll No: <input id="rollNo" type="text" disabled> 

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#name').keyup(function(){
        val = $('#name').val();
        if(!!val){
            $('#age').prop("disabled", false);
            $('#rollNo').prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else{
            $('#age').prop("disabled", true);
            $('#rollNo').prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});

</script>

</body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#Department_id").attr("disabled",true);
   $("#Address_id").attr("disabled",true);

   $(document).on("keypress", "#Organisation_id", function(){
     if($("#Organisation_id").val() !='' || $("#Organisation_id").val()!=NULL)
       {
         $("#Department_id").removeAttr("disabled");
         $("#Address_id").removeAttr("disabled");
       }
      else
       {
         $("#Department_id").attr("disabled",true);
         $("#Address_id").attr("disabled",true);
      }
  });

});
```

Comment: okay, this works however. when organisation name gets populated, Department and Address stay greyed out and i cannot input data

Comment: @Umar Gora I can not get you

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery and check if its empty or not. Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     
     $("#field1").focus();
     
     var error_message = "Please add field 1.";
     
      $("#field1").blur(function() {
          if ($(this).val() != '')
          {
              $("#field2").removeAttr("disabled");    
              $("#message").html("");
          }
     else {              
              $("#field2").attr("disabled", "disabled");  
              alert(error_message);
          }         
     
      });
 });
```

```css
[disabled] {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Field 1: <input id="field1" type="text" /><br/><br/>
Field 2: <input id="field2" type="text" />
```

Hope this helps!